# How to split content in two and add a class

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, class

I have a code that displays the news of the day. I want to split my content into two parts, that is, for the first block, create a class named "**news1**" and for the second "**news2**" as shown in the picture https://ibb.co/ykv7BN4 How can i do this? here is my code

```
import React from 'react';
import newsStyle from './News.module.css';

export class News extends React.Component {
    render() {

        const resultsRender = [];


        for (var i = 0; i < this.props.news.length; i += 2) {
            resultsRender.push(
                <div className={newsStyle.block}>
                    {
                        this.props.news.slice(i, i + 2).map((news, index) => {
                            return (
                                <div className={index % 2 === 0 ? newsStyle.leftContentNews : newsStyle.rightContentNews} key={index}>
                                    <p className={newsStyle.newsTitle}>{news.title}</p>
                                </div>
                            );
                        }

                        )
                    }
                </div>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className={newsStyle.headlineSecond}>
                    <div className={newsStyle.Second}>
                        {resultsRender}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: `<table>`, flexbox, CSS grid or `display: "table"`.

Comment: Many styling options... too many to provide specific help. What have you tried that isn't working that we may assist with?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you would want a `<div>` for each column and append the news of each type to the column's div.